# Pasar elemento Array Bidimensional a un ArrayList

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio en el que se me pide na `Array Bi 5x5` y los relleno con objetos de tipo Coche que he creado en el cual se le pasa una Velocidad y una Marcha.

Después lo que tengo que hacer es pasar los elementos de esa Array Bi que contengan coches que vayan más rápido de `60Km/h` a una `ArrayList`.

Mi código de creación de Array y rellenado automático es el siguiente( no pongo ya donde hago la clase Coche y sus método):

```
Coche tabla[][] = new Coche[5][5];          //Creamos Array Bidimensional de 5x5
    ArrayList <Coche> Rapidos = new ArrayList <Coche>();            //Creamos ArrayList para coches que tengan velocidad mayor a 60.
    ArrayList <Coche> Lentos = new ArrayList <Coche>();             //Creamos ArrayList para coches que tengan velocidad menor o  igul 40.


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {           //Recorremos parte " i " de la matriz
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {           //Recorremos parte " j " de la matriz
            tabla[i][j] = new Coche();              //En cada posición de la matriz se crea un instancia de objeto " Coche"
            tabla[i][j].setVelocidad(Math.round((Math.random() * 110 + 10)));           // En posicion [i][j] se da velocidad entre 20 -120
            tabla[i][j].setMarcha((int) Math.round(Math.random() * 6));         // En posicion [i][j] se da marcha entre 0 - 6

            if ((tabla[i][j].getVelocidad()) > 60) {

                Rapidos.add(new Coche());

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Que error te da exactamente?

Comment: Me creaba bien  la Array Bi pero no sabía como meter los elementos que cumplían la condición del "if >60 ", dentro del Array List que declarara anteriormente. Acaban de ponerme una solución que me vale, solo tenía que poner posición "tabla[i][j]" del coche dentro de "Rapidos.add()", estoy aprendiendo y a veces me lío con ese tipo de cosas. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues viendo lo que necesitas creo que lo mas sencillo y comprensible (aunque poco eficiente) sería crear una estructura de for dentro de otro for para rellenarla y luego pasar a analizar si es rápido o lento con otro for-for.

Podría ser algo así:

```
Coche tabla[][] = new Coche[5][5];          //Creamos Array Bidimensional de 5x5
ArrayList <Coche> Rapidos = new ArrayList <Coche>();            //Creamos ArrayList para coches que tengan velocidad mayor a 60.
ArrayList <Coche> Lentos = new ArrayList <Coche>();             //Creamos ArrayList para coches que tengan velocidad menor o  igul 40.

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {           //Recorremos parte " i " de la matriz
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {           //Recorremos parte " j " de la matriz
        tabla[i][j] = new Coche();              //En cada posición de la matriz se crea un instancia de objeto " Coche"
        tabla[i][j].setVelocidad(Math.round((Math.random() * 110 + 10)));           // En posicion [i][j] se da velocidad entre 20 -120
        tabla[i][j].setMarcha((int) Math.round(Math.random() * 6));         // En posicion [i][j] se da marcha entre 0 - 6
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {           //Recorremos parte " i " de la matriz
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {           //Recorremos parte " j " de la matriz
        if(tabla[i][j].getVelocidad() > 60) {
            Rapidos.add(tabla[i][j]);
        } else {
            Lentos.add(tabla[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Esta seria una manera de resolver el problema. Obviamente los ifs los puedes poner dentro del primer for-for para que sea mas eficiente pero creo que así queda mas diferenciado lo que hace cada uno y es mas comprensible.

Comment: Creo que lo más sencillo y comprensible es recoger el nuevo coche en una variable y al final asignárselo tanto al arreglo de 5x5 como a la lista que corresponda según su velocidad. Así no tienes que recorrer todos de nuevo. Uno de sus problemas claros es que verifica la velocidad de un coche para carga en su lista otro nuevo que no se sabe qué velocidad tiene (si es que tiene alguna con el constructor por defecto)

Comment: Pero yo entiendo que el ejercicio es comprobar los coches de un array[5][5] y ver si su velocidad es mayor o menor de 60. De ahi mi propuesta.

Comment: No es eso lo que está poniendo en el código.

Comment: Mi propuesta es tener un for para cargar los datos en el array y una vez tenemos el Array con los datos proceder a lo que pide el ejercicio según mi entender, comprobar los coches rápidos y los lentos

Comment: Perfecto la aclaración, fallaba en:

`if ((tabla[i][j].getVelocidad()) > 60) {

                Rapidos.add(new Coche());

            }
`

en vez de eso tenía que meter :

`if(tabla[i][j].getVelocidad() > 60) {
            Rapidos.add(tabla[i][j]);
        }`

por lo que @JosepMonclús tú respuesta me ha servido, lo único que en vez de usar dos " for " otra vez he inclído el if dentro del segundo for de donde se crea el Array Bi.

Comment: Perfecto! Me alegro pues, un saludo!